# Mongodb, Verify if my query range is not overlapping a list of Date Ranges in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have the following data:

```
const Availabilities = new Schema({
    id: Number,
    reservations: [{ from: Date, to: Date }]
});
const Availability = mongoose.model('Availability', Availabilities);
```

Basically i want to get a list of products in which the dates do not overlap with the query

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        reservations: [
            {
                from: '2022-01-01',
                to: '2022-03-31',
            },
            {
                from: '2022-04-01',
                to: '2022-06-01',
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        reservations: [
            {
                from: '2022-01-01',
                to: '2022-12-31',
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        reservations: [
            {
                from: '2022-02-01',
                to: '2022-06-30',
            },
        ],
    },
]
```

and I want to filter all those who are not in a specific range.
Example:

```js
query = { from: "2022-07-01", to: "2022-08-31" }
```

should return

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        reservations: [
            {
                from: '2022-01-01',
                to: '2022-03-31',
            },
            {
                from: '2022-04-01',
                to: '2022-06-01',
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        reservations: [
            {
                from: '2022-02-01',
                to: '2022-06-30',
            },
        ],
    },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just check if one of two conditions are met, either:

1. `to` is smaller than the start of your input ( meaning the session ended before )
2. `from` is bigger than the end of your input ( meaning the session started after )

This is how it'll look in code:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      reservations: {
        $elemMatch: {
          $or: [
            {
              to: {
                $lt: "2022-07-01"
              },
              
            },
            {
              from: {
                $gt: "2022-08-31"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      reservations: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$reservations",
          cond: {
            $or: [
              {
                $lt: [
                  "$$this.to",
                  "2022-07-01"
                ]
              },
              {
                $gt: [
                  "$$this.to",
                  "2022-08-31"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/oBzmCfUDIap)